# Firebase notification crashed app in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use firebase to send a notification to all users. When the app is open or in the background(in memory), the Notification is displayed. but when the app terminated and be completely closed and I send the notification, the app crashed, and the "force closed" dialog to show up.

I add this dependence to the flutter app:

```
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
}
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
}
```

And just use this method in main.dart:

```
void setFirebase() async {
await FirebaseMessaging().subscribeToTopic('sajjad');
}
```

How can I fix this error? How can I send a notification to my app when the app is closed?

Comment: please add log errors of the crash event

Comment: @griffins I do not have any log because the app crashes when the app is finished and does not show the android studio log.

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner try something like sentry https://sentry.io/welcome/

Comment: Are you trying this in emulator or real device? If emulator try testing in real device

Comment: add some firebase crash analytics and see share log erros